# Eclipse nodejs vjet v8 debugging

Tags: eclipse, node.js

I am using Eclipse helios and I installed vjet and v8 debugging from the steps in the link below:-
http://jonathan-whywecanthavenicethings.blogspot.in/2011/08/war-of-worlds.html
Also, NodejsTL zip file i downloaded and set it in the build path of my project

But when i am trying to debug it in eclipse via. external tools configuration , I am getting below error:-

```
debugger listening on port 5858

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\workspace\nodejswkspace\TempVjetProject\Server1.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty high chance that eclipse stuck it in a "src" or "source" folder when you set it up. As such the run configuration is basically assuming that your source folder deploys at root.

Double check the pathing and then try again. What I did was eliminate the source folder so I didn't have to deal with--alternatively do something like

```
--debug src/${resource_name}
//or better still since the above shouldn't work for subfolders... 
--debug ${workspace_loc}/${resource_path}
```

I bet your path looks like:

```
E:\eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32\workspace\nodejswkspace\TempVjetProject\***src***\Server1.js
```

Here's what my project looks like now:
[image]

For my configuration this renders: